# Is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(c_n)=\infty \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(c_n)}{n}\neq 0$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let $(c_n)$ be a sequance with $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n\rightarrow c$ and $f(x)$ a function that convegres to infinity for $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(c_n)=\infty$.

I want to proof that every infinite series of the form$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f(c_k)}{k}$ diverges in this case because $a_k=\frac{f(c_k)}{k}$ is not a zero sequence.

Is my assumption
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(c_n)=\infty \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(c_n)}{n}\neq 0$$  correct?

Thoughts:
My gut feeling tells me that it is not so easy, because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(c_n)}{n}\neq 0$ would only be true, if $f(c_n)$ has a higher rate of convergence in comparison to $n$ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $f(c_n)  = \sqrt{n}$ is a counterexample. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} = \infty$, but $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}/n = 0$

Comment: Depending on $(c_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ you may not be able to impose $f(c_n)=\sqrt n$ for all $n$, but the same can be achieved with $f(c_n)=\sqrt{\min\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, c_x=c_n\}}$.

Comment: $(c_n)$ is a random sequence that converges to $c$ and $f$ is also an unspecified function, so it could have the Form that David Lui gave as an example. So my assumption is not true in general because it is at least in one case wrong.